# Upload CSV to BigQuery in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, google-bigquery

Basically what I want to do is to submit a job to BigQuery (Asynchronously), check job status after and print out corresponding status info or error info. I created a frame as below. But I need help on:

1. GoogleApiException: Not Found Job exception when "BigQueryService.Jobs.Get(jobReference.ProjectId, jobReference.JobId).Execute()" was called. My gut is that the job wasn't submit correctly, but I don't know how to do it correctly.
2. How should I handle GoogleApiExceptions?

Firt step: create a Job (uploading CSV file into BigQuery), return the JobReference

```
        TableReference DestTable = new TableReference();
        DestTable.ProjectId = project;
        DestTable.DatasetId = dataset;
        DestTable.TableId = tableId;

        Job Job = new Job();
        JobConfiguration Config = new JobConfiguration();
        JobConfigurationLoad ConfigLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();


        ConfigLoad.Schema = schema;
        ConfigLoad.DestinationTable = DestTable;
        ConfigLoad.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
        ConfigLoad.CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED";
        ConfigLoad.WriteDisposition = createDisposition;
        ConfigLoad.FieldDelimiter = delimiter.ToString();
        ConfigLoad.AllowJaggedRows = true;
        Config.Load = ConfigLoad;
        Job.Configuration = Config;

        //set job reference (mainly job id)
        JobReference JobRef = new JobReference();
        JobRef.JobId = GenerateJobID("Upload");
        JobRef.ProjectId = project;
        Job.JobReference = JobRef;

        using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Open)){
            var JobInfo = BigQueryService.Jobs.Insert(Job,project,fileStream,"text/csv");//application/octet-stream
            JobInfo.UploadAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JobInfo.GetProgress().Status.ToString());
        }
        return JobRef;
```

Then, Pull Job status using projectId and jobId in the returned JobReference from the first step:

```
     while (true)
        {
              pollJob = BigQueryService.Jobs.Get(jobReference.ProjectId, jobReference.JobId).Execute();
                i = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Job status" + jobReference.JobId + ": " + pollJob.Status.State);
                if (pollJob.Status.State.Equals("DONE"))
                {
                    return pollJob;
                }
                // Pause execution for pauseSeconds before polling job status again,
                // to reduce unnecessary calls to the BigQuery API and lower overall
                // application bandwidth.
                Thread.Sleep(pauseSeconds * 1000);

        }
```

Comment: Would be best if you posted your attempted java port so people more familiar with the java way can help you

Comment: The example on this page might be helpful, along with all links that goes from this official documentation page : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local

Answer (score 4):

There's hardly any useful sample code out there showing how to upload a local CSV file to Bigquery table. I eventually get something to work. It might not be the best solution, but it at least works. It's open to any improvement.

```
private JobReference JobUpload(string project, string dataset, string tableId, string filePath, TableSchema schema, string createDisposition, char delimiter)
    {

        TableReference DestTable = new TableReference();
        DestTable.ProjectId = project;
        DestTable.DatasetId = dataset;
        DestTable.TableId = tableId;

        Job Job = new Job();
        JobConfiguration Config = new JobConfiguration();
        JobConfigurationLoad ConfigLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();


        ConfigLoad.Schema = schema;
        ConfigLoad.DestinationTable = DestTable;
        ConfigLoad.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
        ConfigLoad.CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED";
        ConfigLoad.WriteDisposition = createDisposition;
        ConfigLoad.FieldDelimiter = delimiter.ToString();
        ConfigLoad.AllowJaggedRows = true;
        ConfigLoad.SourceFormat = "CSV";
        Config.Load = ConfigLoad;
        Job.Configuration = Config;

        //set job reference (mainly job id)
        JobReference JobRef = new JobReference();
        JobRef.JobId = GenerateJobID("Upload");
        JobRef.ProjectId = project;
        Job.JobReference = JobRef;

        using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Open)){
            JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload InsertMediaUpload = new  JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload(BigQueryService,Job,Job.JobReference.ProjectId,fileStream,"application/octet-stream");
            var JobInfo = InsertMediaUpload.UploadAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JobInfo.Status);
            while (!JobInfo.IsCompleted)
            {
               //wait for the job to be activated and run 
                Console.WriteLine(JobInfo.Status);
            }
        }
        return JobRef;
    }
```

After this, you can actually use the returned JobRef to pull job status, almost the same as we do with Java API:

```
while(true)
{
     PollJob = BigQueryService.Jobs.Get(jobReference.ProjectId, jobReference.JobId).Execute();

     Console.WriteLine("Job status" + jobReference.JobId + ": " + PollJob.Status.State);
     if (PollJob.Status.State.Equals("DONE"))
     {
       return PollJob;
     }
}
```